# Incompatible Types: Cannot Cast View to CheckPreferenceBox

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm playing in the settings someone else made for my app and I want to uncheck a CheckPreferenceBox when the user cannot properly connect to dev servers.
I call my CheckPreferenceBox this way:

```
CheckBoxPreference mCheck = (CheckBoxPreference) findViewById(R.id.prefs_dev_mode);
mCheck.setChecked(false);
```

And here is the part in my .xml file related to it:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/prefs_dev_mode"
        android:key="SP_DEV_SERVER"
        android:title="@string/prefs_server_title"
        android:summary="@string/prefs_server_summary"
        android:defaultValue="false"/>
```

Do you see what could be the error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you face, is that `CheckBoxPreference` is not actually a View. It is a [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html). Therefore the findViewById function will not work for you.

You cannot interact with this element like a View.

If you want to set it unchecked, you should so something like this:

```
CheckBoxPreference pref = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("SP_DEV_SERVER");
pref.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: How would you do it without using deprecated methods?

Comment: `getPreferenceScreen()` isn't deprecated for `PreferenceFragment`. It is generally recommended to use `PreferenceFragment` in `PreferenceActivity`, rather than just `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: That's fine. He is probably introducing you to the basics. The reason that `PreferenceFragment` is good, is that it enables Android to magically structure the preferences according to screen space. Be it showing the headers alone if there isn't much space, or showing the headers on one side, with the preference content itself on the other. If you are being forced to not use fragments, he probably won't mind you using the deprecated method.